# I want to filter out an array of objects by ids in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, immutability

I have an array of objects i.e `queueDetails[{},{}]`. I have another array of ids from response
`"payload":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]`.
I want to `filter` out the ids in payload from `queueDetails` for which I have following code:

```
action.payload.map(payload => {
       state.queueDetails.filter(queue => queue._id !== payload.id)              
})

return {
           ...state,
           queueDetails: ???
        }
```

How do I proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it's safe to guess, you're building part of Redux store reducer, if that's the case, corresponding `case` section for filtering action may be something, like:

```
case FILTER_QUEUE_DETAILS : {
   const { queueDetails } = state,
         { payload } = action,
         submittedIds = payload.map(({id}) => id)
   return {...state, queueDetails: queueDetails.filter(({id}) => !submittedIds.includes(id))}
}
```

You may find the quick demo below:

```js
const { createStore } = Redux
      
const defaultState = {queueDetails:[{id:1,data:'somedata'},{id:2,data:'moredata'},{id:3,data:'somemore'}]},
      FILTER_QUEUE_DETAILS = 'FILTER_QUEUE_DETAILS',
      appReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
        switch(action.type) {
          case FILTER_QUEUE_DETAILS : {
             const { queueDetails } = state,
                   { payload } = action,
                   submittedIds = payload.map(({id}) => id)
             return {...state, queueDetails: queueDetails.filter(({id}) => !submittedIds.includes(id))}
          }
          default: return state
        }
      },
      store = createStore(appReducer)

//initial state
console.log(`// initial state:\n`, store.getState())      

//dispatch action to filter out id's 1, 3
store.dispatch({
  type: FILTER_QUEUE_DETAILS,
  payload: [{id:1},{id:3}]
})

//log resulting state
console.log(`// state upon id's 1 and 3 filtered out:\n`,store.getState())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Consider passing plain array of id's rather than array of objects with single property. That may simply your code and seems logical in general.